# ImageMagick - Incrementing file names over several for loops

Tags: bash, imagemagick, for

This is a Bash question about renaming / incrementing file names with a series of 'for' loops. I don't understand the behavior...

#### Working with the ImageMagick `convert` command

If I do this with say, 3 source files:

```
$ convert *.miff dir/%d.miff
$ convert *.miff dir1/%d.miff
```

I get the expected behavior, with `dir` and `dir1` both containing the files `0.miff 1.miff 2.miff` - this is the required behavior. However `convert` reads all the source images into memory and soaks up resources (Try this with 30 - 40 large image files), not necessarily in strict file order.

This is better, file by file, in strict order, to satisfy the end processing requirement, one file at a time

```
$ for var in `ls -v *.miff`; do convert $var dir/%d.miff; done
$ for var in `ls -v *.miff`; do convert $var dir1/%d.miff; done
```

But, I get `0.miff 1.miff 2.miff` in `dir` and `3.miff 4.miff 5.miff` in `dir1`

I have tried assigning different variables to `*.miff` and `$var` for each loop and using variations on `%d.miff` such as `$((x++)).miff`. No change - incrementing continues upwards instead of resetting to '0' at each 'for' loop.

I have searched for a meaningful answer but suspect this is a behavior embedded in bash and appears to be related to the use of the `$var` variable.

#### EDIT #1

The question is simplified to avoid overwhelming the reader but there are 4 loops, each doing different things, culminating in recombination of the images created in the 4 directories; as follows with the modified script, [per Jesse_p's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457710/7453):

```
x=(0)    
for i in `ls -v *.miff`; do 
  convert "$i" -depth $depth -roll +0+0 -sample 50% B/"$((x++)).miff"
done

x=(0)    
for i in `ls -v *.miff`; do 
  convert "$i" -depth $depth -roll +0+1 -sample 50% G/"$((x++)).miff"
done

x=(0)    
for i in `ls -v *.miff`; do
  convert "$i" -depth $depth -roll +1+0 -sample 50% g/"$((x++)).miff"
done    

x=(0)    
for i in `ls -v *.miff`; do 
  convert "$i" -depth $depth -roll +1+1 -sample 50% R/"$((x++)).miff"
done

for ((R=0,G=0,g=0,B=0;R<=101;R+=1,G+=1,g+=1,B+=1)); do
  convert R/$R.miff G/$G.miff B/$B.miff depth $depth \
     -colorspace sRGB -combine "$((x++))_$name.tiff"    
done
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, that `for f in files..; convert $f dir/%d.jpg; done` just creates `0.jpg` on every run, overwriting the previous ones. Not `0`, `1`, `2` etc, and definitely not using the numbers of files in another directory. So, can you show what you really tried to do?

Comment: I have simplified the code in the question. The image files in each dir are shifted in the x, y axis, using the -roll option. Then the images from each folder are recombined - superpixel demosaic process - there are 4 directores - one for each channel (RGGB). This didn't seem relevant to the question...

Comment: @GeorgeCheshire, You say that you "suspect this is a behavior embedded in bash and appears to be related to the use of the $var variable", and seem to ask for help on that, but you're not showing what it is you're actually asking Bash to do. That makes it rather difficult to tell why it doesn't work, and what you should change.

Comment: For me, it was a difficult question to ask - just how much information to include, without overwhelming the reader. I noticed $var changed the behaviour of the sequence of loops, as opposed to using a glob. I thought that was explained in the body of the question. But thank you and I will reread and edit where necessary - thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Reflecting on your comment I see that 'x' in $((x++)) = '0' in the first instance, incrementing through 4 loops. If I have this right, a glob redefines the same file set each time it is invoked - hence x=0 in the first instance every time. Where a bunch of files are assigned a variable, the incremented value of x carries through to the next loop and increments further. However, regardless of the variable assigned to the files throughout the 4 loops 'x' is still incremented and must therefore be set x=0 prior to each sequential loop.

Comment: ...Therefore, assigning a different variable to the same file set at each sequential loop does not redefine the file set as in the case of using a glob...

Comment: `x` is likely to be empty to begin with, `$(( .. ))` just forces it into a number (zero). Though if there was an `x` in the environment, it could have any numeric value, so it's a good idea to explicitly set it to zero. `x=(0)` actually [makes it an array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) (but referencing it without an index uses index zero, so it still works). `x=0` would be simpler. The variable in `for var in ...` just gets all of the listed values one by one, it's not connected to any arithmetic you do with anything else, so sure, `x`'s value remains unless explicitly reset.

Comment: In that very last loop, you're not zeroing `x` beforehand, which I suppose you'd want to do. Also `R`, `G`, `B` seem to have the same values in the loop, so you could just replace them with a single variable.

Answer (score 1):

According to the ImageMagick [documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/) you can use `-scene` to set the starting sequence number.  (V6.2 and above):

That being said, as ilkkachu points out and my tests have confirmed, your loops will just continuously overwrite a file called `0.miff` and not increment at all.  You could create incrementing files with the following:

```
x=0
for file in *.miff; do convert "$file" "dir/$((x++)).miff"; done
x=0
for file in *.miff; do convert "$file" "dir1/$((x++)).miff"; done
```

`x=0` assigns the value of `0` to the variable named `x`.

`$((x++))` will increment the value of `x` *after* the current operation.  So on run one it will be 0.miff, then 1.miff, etc.  We call `x=0` again between loops to ensure we start back at 0 on the next run.

*note it's better to glob files (*.miff) than to [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)*

Comment: @Jesse_b, `ls -v` can be useful if the filenames have numbers without leading zeroes. It sorts `1`, `2`, `10` correctly, while the default sort order used by the glob probably doesn't. Though of course there are the usual whitespace and glob character issues, but if that's not a problem `ls -v` might be the easiest way to get the sorting right...

Comment: The image sequence is critical for this application as the image channels need to be shifted and then recombined for the same source image.

Comment: x=0 - obviously - too close to the problem... thanks again